# Why isn't the backup file created when running sqlcmd from remote machine?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried running the sqlcmd from a remote host to do a simple backup of a sql 2008 database. The command goes something like this:

```
sqlcmd -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -U username -P some_password -Q "Backup database [db] to \  
disk = 'c:\test_backup.bak' with format"
```

I get a succesfull message but the file isn't created.

When I run this on the sql manager on the same machine, it works. I thought it was permission problems, but I'm using the same username in both cases.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: Did you check the remote SQL server's C: drive to see if the file was created there?

Comment: Checked the remote and no, it wasn't created. Checked locally just in case, but still nothing.... for the error logs...none, the process was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this guide](http://www.sqlservernation.com/home/automated-sql-express-backups.html) .

You need to create a SQL script that backup the database specified in it on the desired location, then you can call that sql script from SQLCMD .

For example if you call the backup script backup.sql :

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -i backup.sql -o output.txt
```

Example of backup.sql :

```
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(1000), @FileName NVARCHAR(255), @FullPath NVARCHAR(1255)
SET @Path = '\\db1\E$\SQLServer\2008\Backups\'
SET @FileName = 'Express_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), '/', '') + '.bak'
SET @FullPath = @Path + @FileName

BACKUP DATABASE Express
TO DISK = @FullPath
WITH INIT
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server is running Windows 2008 or higher it might have problems writing the file to the root of the drive.  I've seen this before.  Create a folder on the C:\ and backup the file to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Op, are you expecting the backup file to appear on the remote host where you're executing sqlcmd?

If so, you need to specify a UNC path instead of a local (to the host executing sqlcmd) path.  The SQL Server does not recognize the remote-host's local path....